# Unexpected render loop while using useReducer (and no useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm attempting to build authentication in to an application that I'm building. This particular application won't/shouldn't be accessible except by users within a specific Microsoft Azure tenancy. For that reason, rather than creating a login page and all of its functionality, I decided to just check the users browser for a valid token (acquireTokenSilent) and if that fails, give them a popup to login to. However, after I got authentication working correctly, I found that the App was being rerendered continuously.

I've since created a [codesandbox without the complications of MSAL and am getting the exact same behavior](https://codesandbox.io/s/auth-example-sprql).

I'm new to reducers, but I didn't think a rerender would occur unless state changed. I found a [similar issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16537), but it depends on the usage of useEffect to reproduce, which I'm not utilizing currently. Where am I misunderstanding how things work?

**/auth.js**

```
export default class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.handleAuthentication = this.handleAuthentication.bind(this);
  }
  getProfile() {
    return {
      username: "FakeUser",
      name: "John Doe",
      email: "jd@fakeusers.net"
    };
  }

  handleAuthentication() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      console.log("handle Authentication function hit");
      //fake auth
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("timeout occurred, resolving.");
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

**/AuthApp.js**

```
import React, { useReducer, createContext } from "react";
import Auth from "./auth.js";

const auth = new Auth();
const UserContext = createContext();

const initialState = {
  auth: false,
  user: null
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log("reducer hit!", action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "loginUser":
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        isAuthenticated: action.payload.authenticated,
        userProfile: action.payload.user
      };
    default:
      console.log("Reducer hit without a payload!", action);
      return state;
  }
};

const UserContextProvider = props => {
  console.log("UserContextProvider Element rendering...");
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState.user);
  auth.handleAuthentication().then(() => {
    dispatch({
      type: "loginUser",
      payload: {
        authenticated: true,
        user: auth.getProfile()
      }
    });
  });
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <UserContextProvider>
      <UserContext.Consumer>
        {user =>
          user.isAuthenticated ? (
            <div>{JSON.stringify(user)}</div>
          ) : (
            <div>You are not logged in.</div>
          )
        }
      </UserContext.Consumer>
    </UserContextProvider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece that was missing was the fact that useEffect or useMemo is required here. You need to check to see if further authentication is required rather than just having it exist in the function like you would in a constructor.